# Remove repeated lines in a file based on pattern

Tags: python, perl

I've tried to find a good way to carry out this, but unfortunatly I didn't find one.

I'm working with files with this format:

> =Cluster=
>   SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22491.xml;spectrum=1074 true
>   SPEC  PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=2950 true
>
> =Cluster=
>   SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=1876 true
>   SPEC  PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=3479 true
>   SPEC  PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=3785 true
>
> =Cluster=
>   SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22493.xml;spectrum=473  true
>   SPEC  PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22493.xml;spectrum=473  true

As you can see, every SPEC line is different, except the last one, where number of the string spectrum is repeated. 
What I'd like to do is take every chunk of information between the pattern `=Cluster=` and check if there are lines with spectrum value repeated. In case there are several lines repeated, removes all except one.

The output file should be like this:

> =Cluster=
>   SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22491.xml;spectrum=1074 true
>   SPEC  PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=2950 true
>
> =Cluster=
>   SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=1876 true
>   SPEC  PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=3479 true
>   SPEC  PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22498.xml;spectrum=3785 true
>
> =Cluster=
>   SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22493.xml;spectrum=473  true

I'm using this to split the file using the pattern but I don't know how to check if there are spectrum repeated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef $/;
$_ = <>;
$n = 0;

for $match (split(/(?==Cluster=)/)) {
      open(O, '>temp' . ++$n);
      print O $match;
      close(O);
}
```

PD: I used Perl because it's easier for me, but I understand python as well.

Comment: Are duplicate lines consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will remove duplicate lines (globally across the file).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen; 

while ( <> ) {
  next if ( m/SPEC/ and $seen{$_}++ );
  print;
}
```

If you want to be more specific about the spectrum value, for example:

```
next if ( m/spectrum=(\d+)/ and $seen{$1}++ );
```

As you're splitting out your clusters, you can do something quite similar, but just:

```
  if ( $line =~ m/==Cluster==/ ) { 
     open ( $output, ">", "temp".$count++ ); 
     select $output;
  }
```

This sets the default 'print' location to `$output` (you'll need to declare it outside your loop too.

You should also:

- `use strict;` `use warnings;`
- Avoid reading `<>` into `$_`, it's unnecessary. But it'd generally be better if you had to, to `$block = do { local $/; <> };` instead. And then `$block =~ m/regex/`
- Use lexical file handles: `open ( my $output, '>', 'filename' ) or die $!;`
- check your return code on open (`or die $!` is usually sufficient).

So that would be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen; 
my $count = 0; 
my $output; 

while (  <> ) {
  next if ( m/spectrum=(\d+)/ and $seen{$1}++ );
  if ( m/==Cluster==/ ) { 
     open ( $output, ">", "temp".$count++ ) or die $!; 
     select $output;
  }
  print;
}
```

Comment: One silly question. How could a remove semicolon character duplicated before the `next if` and after generate the new file? I was thinking to use ´$str =~ s/;+/;/g;´but I don't really know how add to your code. 
Thanks!

Comment: Without specifying `=~` there default thing to operate on is `$_` or the current block. So all you need is `s/;+/;/g;` and that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can, also, use this `python`script in which i used `groupby` from `itertools` module.

I assume your input file is called `f_input.txt` and the output file is called `new_file.txt`.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = (k.rstrip().split("=Cluster=") for k in open("f_input.txt", 'r'))
final = list(k for k,_ in groupby(list(data)))

with open("new_file.txt", 'a') as f:
    for k in final:
        if k == ['','']:
            f.write("=Cluster=\n")
        elif k == ['']:
            # write '\n\n' in Windows and '\n' in Linux (tested only in Windows!)
            f.write("\n\n")
        else:
            f.write("{}\n".join(k))
```

The output file `new_file.txt` will be similar to your desired output.

Comment: This work also, but this script remove SPEC as well. I just want to remove the line repeated, not the words repeated.

Answer (score 0):

If duplicate lines are consecutive, you could use this perl oneliner:

```
perl -ani.back -e 'next if defined($p) && $_ eq $p;$p=$_;print' file.txt
```

The original file is backup with extension `.back`

Comment: Thanks for downvotes! What's wrong with this answer?

Comment: @Toto no idea... I give you one up ;)

Comment: @Enrique: Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The task seems easy enough to not require perl/python: use the [`uniq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) command to remove adjacent duplicate lines:

```
$ uniq < input.txt > output.txt
```